# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application. run the project with gradle

Tags: java, javafx

I am building a java project in intellij. I alreadly imported the gradle script and build.gradle file can be successfully built. However, when I ran my java files, this error occurs: "JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application". I am really not sure what is the issue.
This is my Main.java file:
[image]

This is the launcher
[image]

and this is the Duke.java files:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class Duke extends Application {

    private Storage storage;
    private TaskList tasks;
    private Ui ui;

    private ScrollPane scrollPane;
    private VBox dialogContainer;
    private TextField userInput;
    private Button sendButton;
    private Scene scene;
    private Image user = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/DaUser.png"));
    private Image duke = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/DaDuke.png"));

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        //Step 1. Setting up required components

        //The container for the content of the chat to scroll.
        scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        dialogContainer = new VBox();
        scrollPane.setContent(dialogContainer);

        userInput = new TextField();
        sendButton = new Button("Send");

        AnchorPane mainLayout = new AnchorPane();
        mainLayout.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane, userInput, sendButton);

        scene = new Scene(mainLayout);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        stage.setTitle("Duke");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setMinHeight(600.0);
        stage.setMinWidth(400.0);

        mainLayout.setPrefSize(400.0, 600.0);

        scrollPane.setPrefSize(385, 535);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);

        scrollPane.setVvalue(1.0);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        // You will need to import `javafx.scene.layout.Region` for this.
        dialogContainer.setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);

        userInput.setPrefWidth(325.0);

        sendButton.setPrefWidth(55.0);

        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollPane, 1.0);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(sendButton, 1.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(sendButton, 1.0);

        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(userInput, 1.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(userInput, 1.0);

        sendButton.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
            handleUserInput();
        });

        userInput.setOnAction((event) -> {
            handleUserInput();
        });

        dialogContainer.heightProperty().addListener((observable) -> scrollPane.setVvalue(1.0));

    }

    private void handleUserInput() {
        Label userText = new Label(userInput.getText());
        Label dukeText = new Label(getResponse(userInput.getText()));
        dialogContainer.getChildren().addAll(
                DialogBox.getUserDialog(userText.getText(), user),
                DialogBox.getDukeDialog(dukeText.getText(), duke)
        );
        userInput.clear();
    }

    public String getResponse(String input) {
        return "Duke heard: " + input;
    }

    public Duke(String filePath) {
        ui = new Ui();
        storage = new Storage(filePath);
        try {
            tasks = new TaskList(storage.load());
        } catch (DukeException e) {
            ui.showLoadingError();
            tasks = new TaskList();
        }
    }

    public Duke() {
        this("data/duke.txt");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Duke("data/duke.txt").run();
    }

    public void run() {
        ui.showWelcome();

        boolean isExit = false;

        while (!isExit) {
            try {
                String fullCommand = ui.readCommand();
                ui.showLine(); 
                Command c = Parser.parse(fullCommand);
                c.execute(tasks, ui, storage);
                isExit = c.isExit();
            } catch (DukeException e) {
                ui.showError(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                ui.showLine();
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

update: I imported the lib folder into my project and now the error is gone. But another error occurs when I ran the project, which is "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null"

Comment: What JRE / JDK do you use? Most OpenJREs can't run javafx applications.

Comment: I am using java 11.

Comment: I am not sure if it is about Duke.java file. I actually just copy paste some files from another basic javafx tutorial project, and that project runs properly. When copying pasting to my own project, I didn't change the Duke file because I am not sure how to change it to adapt to the javafx so I don't know if it is the problem.

Comment: and in the Duke class there is also a main funtion. do I need to change that?

Comment: But what kind of java 11 JRE? [openJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/), [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html#), [OracleJRE](https://www.java.com/en/download/)? The Duke class should be ok. If this class would be the problem that would lead to a different exception.

Comment: This is the what I get from command prompt:
java 13.0.2 2020-01-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I think it is oraclejre

Comment: Oracle's jre usually works fine with javafx (at least when I tried it). In this case I don't know what the problem might be. But there are many questions (and answers) on similar problems on SO that you can check out: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+runtime+components+missing

Comment: so just now I imported the lib folder into my project and now the error is gone. But another error occurs when I ran the project, which is "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null"

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510). Probably the image resources were not found, but you better start a new question on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63664880/error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-run-this-appli#comment112581324_63664880) you are using Java 13 and not Java 11.

JavaFX is **not** part of the JDK in Java 13 and also not in Java 11. You can get JavaFX from [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/). Then you need to add the JavaFX JAR files to your *module path* because since JDK 9, java uses modules.

Unrelated to your question, but the "system" properties contain details about the java version, for example...

```java
System.getProperty("java.runtime.version");
```